# SDO_GEOMETRY not accepting variables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm trying to display the distance between to locations, however, when using `l_lng` and `l_lat` variables that are processed from a postcode a user enters, I'm getting the following error - `ORA-13032: Invalid NULL SDO_GEOMETRY object`

It's not a problem with the `UPDATE` as when I input latitude and longitude values, the distance is calculated. Also, when displaying the latitude and longitude values held in the `l_lng` and `l_lat` variables, they are also correct.

```
DECLARE

  l_lat VARCHAR2(100);
  l_lng VARCHAR2(100);
  l_postcode VARCHAR2(8) := :P2_POSTCODE;

BEGIN

    brian.GEOCODE_GM_XML (:P2_POSTCODE, l_lat, l_lng);

    UPDATE RESTAURANTS 
    SET DISTANCE =     (SELECT SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE(
                            restaurants.location, 
                            SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 4326, SDO_POINT_TYPE(l_lng, l_lat, null), null, null), 
                            0.005, 'unit=mile') distance
                       FROM restaurants WHERE restaurants.restaurant_id = 36);
    htp.p(l_lat);
    htp.p(l_lng);

END;
```

Is there any mistake I'm making?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Change variable declarations for `l_lat` and `l_lng` from `varchar2`
  to `number`.
- I presume the `restaurants.distance` column is of type `number`.
- Verify that the geometries have valid fields. To specify a *NULL*
  geometry, specify the whole `SDO_GEOMETRY` as
  *NULL* instead of setting each field to *NULL*.  It seems you may have  some values are *NULL* at the same time for both `l_lat` and
  `l_lng` of `SDO_POINT_TYPE`.